# ffmpeg tee muxer failing with error: Tag avc1 incompatible with output codec id '28'

Tags: ffmpeg

I am able to stream with ffmpeg an mp4 file with h264 encoded video and aac encoded audio to flash flv output. The command I used is:

`ffmpeg -re -i bigbuckbunny_HD_60fps.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.3.64:1935/main/stream0`

When I am trying to use the tee option to duplicate the output I am failing with an error. This is the command I use:

`ffmpeg -re -i bigbuckbunny_HD_60fps.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://192.168.3.64:1935/main/stream0|[f=flv]rtmp://192.168.3.64:1935/main/stream1"`

However, it fails. What I am missing? The output I have from ffmpeg is:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bigbuckbunny_HD_60fps.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.29.104
  Duration: 00:10:34.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4279 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4141 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[flv @ 0x24607a0] Tag avc1 incompatible with output codec id '28' ([7][0][0][0])
[tee @ 0x2365260] Slave '[f=flv]rtmp://192.168.3.64:1935/mainconcept/stream0': error writing header: Invalid data found when processing input
[tee @ 0x2365260] Slave muxer #0 failed, aborting.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ffmpeg `-f tee` refuses to do anything useful](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/ffmpeg-f-tee-refuses-to-do-anything-useful) add `-tag:v 7` (or `-vtag 7`, same thing):

```
ffmpeg -re -i bigbuckbunny_HD_60fps.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -tag:v 7 -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://192.168.3.64:1935/main/stream0|[f=flv]rtmp://192.168.3.64:1935/main/stream1"
```

If you get error `Tag mp4a incompatible with output codec id '86018'` add `-tag:a 10` / `-atag 10`:

```
ffmpeg -re -i bigbuckbunny_HD_60fps.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -tag:v 7 -tag:a 10 -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://192.168.3.64:1935/main/stream0|[f=flv]rtmp://192.168.3.64:1935/main/stream1"
```

Related bug report is [#6258: tee muxer fails on stream copy](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6258).

Comment: once -tag:a 10 was added it worked. Thanks